# Thread group leaves a zombie thread after calling interrupt

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, interrupt

I have a supervisor thread and a few worker threads. Let us suppose that we have elves that wrap up gifts and send them to the factory, which places them in a queue. After a certain number of gifts, the supervisor tells the works to stop.

All my worker threads belong to a thread group. When the supervisor realizes that the required number of gifts has been reached, it calls workersThreadGroup.interrupt(). However, there is always a zombie worker remaining which continues to produce.

Now, for some code:

```
public class Factory implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        createElves();
        startElves();

        while (goalNotAchieved) {
            orchestrator.awaitSupervisorTurn();
            System.out.println("Factory " + factoryID + " is working..");
            orchestrator.setWorkersTurn();


        }


        System.out.println("Factory " + factoryID + " FINISHED");
        joinElves();

    }


    private void joinElves() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElves; i++) {
            try {
                elvesThreads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startElves() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElves; i++) {
            elvesThreads[i].start();
        }
    }

    private void createElves() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElves; i++) {
            IPosition elfPosition = positionBuilder.create(matrixSize, elfMap);
            ElfRunnable elfRunnable = elfBuilder.create(i, this, elfPosition,
                                                        orchestrator);
            elfMap.addEntry(elfRunnable, elfPosition);
            elfPosition.setOwner(elfRunnable);
            elvesThreads[i] = new Thread(elvesThreadGroup, elfRunnable);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void queryPositions() {
        try {
            positionQuerySemaphore.acquire();
            System.out.println("Factory " + factoryID + " starting query....");
            for (ElfRunnable elf : elves) {
                System.out.println("Queried " + elf + ": (" + elf.getElfPosition());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            positionQuerySemaphore.release();
        }

    }


    public synchronized void notifyGiftCreated(Gift gift) {
        if (producedGifts == maxGifts) {
            elvesThreadGroup.interrupt();
            goalNotAchieved = false;
            orchestrator.setWorkersTurn();
            System.out.println("Rejecting " + gift);

        } else {
            producedGifts++;
            System.out.println("GIFTS: " + producedGifts);
        }


    }

}


public class ElfRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        notifySupervisorFactory();
        while (threadIsAlive()) {

            orchestrator.awaitWorkersTurn();
            if (elfPosition.randomMove()) {
                Gift gift = new Gift(random.nextInt(), ID);
                orchestrator.setSuperVisorTurn();
                supervisorFactory.notifyGiftCreated(gift);
                rest();
            } else {
                awaitRandom();
            }


        }
        System.out.println("Elf " + ID + "/" + supervisorFactory + " is DONE");
    }

    private boolean threadIsAlive() {
        return !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();
    }


    private void notifySupervisorFactory() {
        supervisorFactory.becomeAware(this);
    }

    private void rest() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }

    }

    private void awaitRandom() {

        int minimum = 10;
        int maximum = 50;
        int waitingTime = random.nextInt(maximum - minimum) + minimum;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(waitingTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }


}


public class Orchestrator implements IDefinitions {
    private volatile int turn;

    public Orchestrator(int turn) {
        this.turn = turn;
    }

    public synchronized void awaitWorkersTurn() {
        while (turn == supervisorTurn) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void awaitSupervisorTurn() {
        while (turn == workerTurn ) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    public synchronized void setWorkersTurn() {
        turn = workerTurn;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void setSuperVisorTurn() {
        turn = supervisorTurn;
        notifyAll();
    }



}
```

Now, what i get during output:

```
Factory 0 got: 20 toys to produce, 347 as matrix size, 5 elves
Thread elf 0/0 group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
Thread elf 1/0 group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
Thread elf 2/0 group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
Thread elf 3/0 group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
Thread elf 4/0 group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
Factory 0 is working..
Elf 1 created a gift
Elf 3 created a gift
Elf 0 created a gift
Elf 4 created a gift
Elf 2 created a gift
Factory 0 is working..
GIFTS: 1
GIFTS: 2
GIFTS: 3
GIFTS: 4
GIFTS: 5
Elf 4 created a gift
Elf 2 created a gift
Elf 3 created a gift
Factory 0 is working..
GIFTS: 6
Elf 1 created a gift
Elf 0 created a gift
Factory 0 is working..
GIFTS: 7
GIFTS: 8
GIFTS: 9
GIFTS: 10
Elf 2 created a gift
GIFTS: 11
Elf 0 created a gift
GIFTS: 12
Elf 4 created a gift
Elf 3 created a gift
Factory 0 is working..
Elf 1 created a gift
GIFTS: 13
Factory 0 is working..
GIFTS: 14
GIFTS: 15
Elf 2 created a gift
Elf 4 created a gift
Elf 0 created a gift
Factory 0 is working..
GIFTS: 16
GIFTS: 17
GIFTS: 18
Elf 1 created a gift
Elf 3 created a gift
GIFTS: 19
Factory 0 is working..
GIFTS: 20
Elf 4 created a gift
Elf 0 created a gift
Elf 2 created a gift
Rejecting Gift--820046672-4
Factory 0 is working..
Elf 4/0 is DONE
Elf 1 created a gift
Elf 3 created a gift
----------------Factory 0 FINISHED----------------
Rejecting Gift-1775300653-2
Rejecting Gift--906406470-0
Elf 2/0 is DONE
Rejecting Gift--778562716-3
Elf 0/0 is DONE
Elf 3/0 is DONE
Rejecting Gift-912276334-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift--203717575-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift--504209300-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift--1405618643-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift-472265871-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift-1573561986-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift-2005222080-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift-1722629349-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift-678251744-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift--1911462918-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift-994905496-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift--1700057698-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift-2040969141-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift--135605836-1
Elf 1 created a gift
Rejecting Gift--1320452586-1
```

As you can see, there is always one zombie thread running. Why is this so ?

Comment: I see you are ignoring all the InterruptedExceptions. This is probably not a good idea, and may be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is that you want to cancel/stop your worker threads with the interupt() method, but in the same time you are calling methods on the thread that will throw interrupted exception if the thread is already interrupted and this will cleared the interrupt status.

So as an example what can happen in your code:

your elf run method cycle:

```
while (threadIsAlive()) {

1)           //dostuff -> while you are doing the stuff, supervisor call threadGroup.interrupt()
2)           awaitRandom();
}
```

1) during your doStuff code, supervisor calls **threadGroup.interrupt()**, this will set the interrupt status on your thread and if you call Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted() you will get true

2) here you are calling sleep() method, sleep method will throw an **InterruptedException** if its called on already interrupted thread, and it will clear the interrupt status! 
check javadoc:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)
so if you call the  **threadIsAlive()** the method **Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()** will return false.

So what you can do you can catch the interrputedException in awaitRandom()( and in all other methods that throws InterruptedExceptions and clear the interrupt status) method and set the interrupt status again like this:

```
 try {
            Thread.sleep(waitingTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //restores the interrupt status
}
```

But much more better option is to cancel/stop the threads via some another mechanism than with the interrupt flag. You can introduce some new volatile flag stop variable in your worker thread(similiarly as you are doing with goalNotAchieved), and you can set this variable if you want to cancel/stop thread.

Comment: Oh my god, I bashed my head around this for sooo long. I forgot that sleep clears the interrupted status. Thank you!